# Sprites spawning in incorrect position

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I have a row of 5 sprites and they spawn every 4 seconds and move down along the Y-axis. The sprites are spawning the correct amount each time, I have 5 sprites equal spaced apart across the screen, they're all center perfectly.

However when the performSelector action is called, when it spawns them in they don't go to the right position. The move over to the left so far that I can only see half a sprite on the left side of the screen. After testing it, it seems they are all stacked on top of each other at the wrong position.

Any idea whats going on? I'd appreciate any help. Here's all the code I'm using in the scene.

```
-(void) addBricks:(CGSize)size {
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    //create brick sprite from image
    SKSpriteNode *brick = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"brick"];
    //resize bricks
    brick.size = CGSizeMake(60, 30);
    //psoition bricks
    int xPos = size.width/7.5 * (i+.5);
    int yPos = 450;
    brick.position = CGPointMake(xPos, yPos);

    //add move action
    SKAction *wait = [SKAction waitForDuration:3];
    SKAction *move = [SKAction moveByX:0 y:-36.9 duration:1];
    SKAction *sequence = [SKAction sequence:@[wait, move]];
    SKAction *repeatMove = [SKAction repeatActionForever:sequence];


    [brick runAction:repeatMove];
    [self addChild:brick];

}
}

-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {
if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {
    self.backgroundColor = [SKColor colorWithRed:(243.0f/255) green:(228.0f/255) blue:(165.0f/255) alpha:1.0];

    //add action to spawn bricks
    SKAction *spawn = [SKAction performSelector:@selector(addBricks:) onTarget:(self)];
    SKAction *delay = [SKAction waitForDuration:4];
    SKAction *delayThenSpawn = [SKAction sequence:@[delay, spawn]];

    [self runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:delayThenSpawn]];

    [self addBricks:size];


}
return self;
}
```

Comment: I'm curious as to what values are being passed into addBricks: for the CGSize argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as LearnCocos2D mentioned in your last question.. you cant use a selector when youre passing a parameter into a method.

`addBricks` expects `size` ..  you arent passing size into it.

change your spawn action to

```
SKAction *spawn = [SKAction runBlock:^{
    // make this whatever size you want, i'm just using the scene's size
    [self addBricks:self.size];
}];
```

that should get you started